mdadm: Value "/dev/md128" cannot be set as devname. Reason: Not POSIX compatible
I am currently stuck after upgrading mdadm version
mdadm --version
mdadm - v4.2 - 2021-12-30 - 14

One of my RAID arrays (named md128) failed, and after adding a new drive to resync it
I get the following error:
mdadm: Value "/dev/md128" cannot be set as devname. Reason: Not POSIX compatible.

I can't get the RAID to resync because of this naming problem.
This is a production machine, so booting into rescue mode to recreate the RAID is not a feasible option.
Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Downgraded to mdadm v4.1 and readded, and upgraded back to the same version
Reboot and everything works fine.
